# Class Diagram generated by VisualStudio doesn't update itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

VS 2010 Pro: I have generated a class diagram for my library, now added some more classes to it, but the class diagram is only showing the older classes and doesn't get updated automatically.
So I am wondering if this is how it is and I should delete and re-add the class diagram every time ? or these is something I should do in VS IDE to get it updated?

Comment: right click on the file and press "generate class diagram" should do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just *drag&drop* your **new classes onto the diagramm** or choose **generate class diagram** out of the *contextMenu* of the new class(es).

New classes won't be shown automatically. Once a class is on a diagramm it will be updated anytime you change it's members!

Comment: hmm...then I think it is just easier to remove class diagram, generate a new one when we have added a couple of new classes... I wish VS was smart enough to realize there are new classes and itsself update the diagram tho.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am wondering if this is how it is

yes.

> and I should delete and re-add the class diagram every time ?

No. You can view changes done to already added classes. To see new classes you can **drag n drop** them to designer surface.

If you want to view dynamic class dependency you can use architecture explorer. I guess it is only with VS Ultimate. Not sure about Pro. You can generate dependency graph by assembly or namespace. It's nice and fancy :) Very useful to explore cyclic dependency or identifying hubs in the graph. This you don't need to create. It's generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-build the project where your classes in.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio
Remove the ".ncb" file which is located next to your solution file.
Open your solution with Visual Studio
Rebuild the solution.
The class diagram is now updated.